# New menu item not showing up

Tags: odoo

I'm using OpenERP 7.0, and I've extended `products` with a `products_available_at` table, and I've added a menu option `Locations` under Sales - Configuration - Products.  The menu item shows up just fine if I'm logged in as admin, but is missing for anybody else.

Any ideas how to make the menu item show up for everyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be a security issue. Please check whether you have provided security for the new model and also for the menu.

Settings -> Technical -> Security -> [Record Rules | Access Controls List]